# Ionic2 - angular2 http post request returns an error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I try to send post request on my ionic2 application , when call to post method then return an error but not have an any message. I think that I do wrong anyone on angular2 post request.

Here is my function for request;

```
load(username, password){
    let body = new FormData();
     body.append('email', username);
     body.append('password', password);
    let headers = new Headers({
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers,  method: "post" });

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
debugger;
    this.http
        .post('http://asis-services.com/AsisTransitApi/token', body, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
              console.log(data);
            },
            err => {
              console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
            }
        );
  }
  )};
```

you can look result;

[post request gets an error at the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFxEo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.That is a permission problem for ionic 2 applications.If you are developping ionic 2 app in ionic serve mode and you use angular2 post method with authentication header, http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/ help your problem, basically you should add chrome extension then you can easily call your post method on ajax.